# AWS Lambda function that executes 5000+ promises to AWS SQS is extremely unreliable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await, aws-lambda

I'm writing a Node AWS Lambda function that queries around 5,000 items from my DB and sends them via messages into an AWS SQS queue.

My local environment involves me running my lambda with AWS SAM local, and emulating AWS SQS with [GoAWS](https://github.com/p4tin/GoAws).

An example skeleton of my Lambda is:

```
async run() {
  try {
    const accounts = await this.getAccountsFromDB();
    const results = await this.writeAccountsIntoQueue(accounts);
    return 'I\'ve written: ' + results + ' messages into SQS';
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught error running job: ');
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  }
}
```

There are no performance issues with my `getAccountsFromDB()` function and it runs almost instantly, returning me an array of 5,000 accounts.

My `writeAccountsIntoQueue` function looks like:

```
async writeAccountsIntoQueue(accounts) {
  // Extract the sqsClient and queueUrl from the class 
  const { sqsClient, queueUrl } = this;
  try {
    // Create array of functions to concurrenctly call later
    let promises = accounts.map(acc => async () => await sqsClient.sendMessage({
        QueueUrl: queueUrl,
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(acc),
        DelaySeconds: 10,
      })
    );

    // Invoke the functions concurrently, using helper function `eachLimit`
    let writtenMessages = await eachLimit(promises, 3);
    return writtenMessages;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Error writing accounts into queue');
    console.log(e);
    return e;
  }
}
```

My helper, `eachLimit` looks like:

```
async function eachLimit (funcs, limit) {
  let rest = funcs.slice(limit);
  await Promise.all(
    funcs.slice(0, limit).map(
      async (func) => {
        await func();
        while (rest.length) {
          await rest.shift()();
        }
      }
    )
  );
}
```

To the best of my understanding, it should be limiting concurrent executions to `limit`.

Additionally, I've wrapped the AWS SDK SQS client to return an object with a `sendMessage` function that looks like:

```
sendMessage(params) {
  const { client } = this;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    client.sendMessage(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error sending message');
        console.log(err);
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve(data);
    });
  });
}
```

So nothing fancy there, just Promisifying a callback.

I've got my lambda set up to timeout after 300 seconds, and the lambda always times out, and if it doesn't it ends abruptly and misses some final logging that should go on, which makes me thing it may even be erroring somewhere, silently. When I check the SQS queue I'm missing around 1,000 entries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can see a couple of issues in your code,

First:

```
    let promises = accounts.map(acc => async () => await sqsClient.sendMessage({
        QueueUrl: queueUrl,
        MessageBody: JSON.stringify(acc),
        DelaySeconds: 10,
      })
    );
```

You're abusing `async / await`. Always bear in mind `await` will wait until your promise is resolved before continuing with the next one, in this case whenever you map the array `promises` and call each function item it will wait for the promise wrapped by that function before continuing, which is bad. Since you're only interested in getting the promises back, you could simply do this instead:

```
const promises = accounts.map(acc => () => sqsClient.sendMessage({
       QueueUrl: queueUrl,
       MessageBody: JSON.stringify(acc),
       DelaySeconds: 10,
    })
);
```

Now, for the second part, your `eachLimit` implementation looks wrong and very verbose, I've refactored it with help of [es6-promise-pool](https://github.com/timdp/es6-promise-pool) to handle the concurrency limit for you:

```
const PromisePool = require('es6-promise-pool')

function eachLimit(promiseFuncs, limit) {    
    const promiseProducer = function () {
        while(promiseFuncs.length) {
            const promiseFunc = promiseFuncs.shift();
            return promiseFunc();
        }

        return null;
    }

    const pool = new PromisePool(promiseProducer, limit)
    const poolPromise = pool.start();
    return poolPromise;
}
```

Lastly, but very important, have a look at [SQS Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/limits-messages.html), SQS FIFO has up to 300 sends / sec. Since you are processing 5k items, you could probably up your concurrency limit to 5k / (300 + 50) , approx 15. The 50 could be any positive number, just to move away from the limit a bit.
Also, considering using [SendMessageBatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessageBatch.html) which you could have much more throughput and reach 3k sends / sec.

***EDIT***

As I suggested above, using `sendMessageBatch` the throughput is much better, so I've refactored the code mapping your promises to support `sendMessageBatch`:

```
function chunkArray(myArray, chunk_size){
    var index = 0;
    var arrayLength = myArray.length;
    var tempArray = [];

    for (index = 0; index < arrayLength; index += chunk_size) {
        myChunk = myArray.slice(index, index+chunk_size);
        tempArray.push(myChunk);
    }

    return tempArray;
}

const groupedAccounts = chunkArray(accounts, 10);

const promiseFuncs = groupedAccounts.map(accountsGroup => {
    const messages = accountsGroup.map((acc,i) => {
        return {
            Id: `pos_${i}`,
            MessageBody: JSON.stringify(acc),
            DelaySeconds: 10
        }
    });

    return () => sqsClient.sendMessageBatch({
        Entries: messages,
        QueueUrl: queueUrl
     })
});
```

Then you can call `eachLimit` as usual:

```
const result = await eachLimit(promiseFuncs, 3);
```

The difference now is every promise processed will send a batch of messages of size n (10 in the example above).

Comment: I believe some engines are smart enough now to inline some of the Promise chains that just return another Promise. I maybe wrong - would need to be benchtested on the later chrome/nodejs builds.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and insights. I've made your changes and after running again it looks like the lambda spent some time executing but then suddenly dropped off. After checking the queue, it looks like 5266 items were entered into it, but 5501 should have been written. Any idea as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Is hard to say. Are you getting any errors? What concurrency limit did you set?  Also, you should try with real SQS and compare the results there against GoAWS.

Comment: No errors or output, I even tied on a `.then(d => {console.log('success')})` to the `sqsClient.sendMessage(...)` as well as a counter and I see it happening around 5266 times, hang, then just quit with no more output or any errors. I set the concurrency to 10, and when I get home I can try this against normal SQS

Comment: "You're abusing async / await" should have been "You're *misusing* async / await".

Comment: Thanks again! I was able to get localstack SQS to work with my lambda on the same Docker network, not sure why it didn't before, and batching was something I was planning on getting around to but GoAws didn't support it! Your chunking/batching functions work great, and the lambda seems to be doing its job!